# PHP simplexml group by id

Tags: php, xml

i have a feed which has products -> product in it, where are different fields like id, name, price.

The id can be sometimes the same, so i want to group it or just showing the first which i found.

As an example:

```
<product>
  <pid>
  792422100
  <pid>
  <name>
  Produtname
  </name>
  <price>
  10.00$
  </price>
</product>
<product>
  <pid>
  792422100
  <pid>
  <name>
  Produtname 2
  </name>
  <price>
  10.00$
  </price>
</product>
```

So like that, there where the pid is the same.

I get it printed with

```
foreach ($xml->product as $item) {
  echo $item->pid;
  echo $item->name;
  echo $item->price; 
}
```

But i dont want to print products with same pid multiple...
Is there a way to group by pid or just showing the first pid of the list unique?

Answer (score 0):

You can check duplicate ID by recording them in an array or string. Something like this:

```
<?php

$idList = array();

foreach ($xml->product as $item) {
    if (array_search($item->pid, $idList) <= 0) {
        array_push($idList, $item->pid);
        echo $item->pid;
        echo $item->name;
        echo $item->price;
    }
}

?>
```